# MFC canned DllMain does not call ExitInstance for DLL_PROCESSS_DETACH?

Tags: windows, dll, mfc, dynamic-linking

The canned DllMain for MFC 8.0 does not seem to call ExitInstance when it gets a DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.  One possible solution is to define my own DllMain, but how do I tell the linker to use mine and not MFC's?

Or, is there another override which gets called on DLL_PROCESS_DETACH I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues for a project compiled with /clr. Are you in the same situation? I was never able to trace it to a specific condition, but changing some static initializers to set null cleared it up. I think it has something to do with the order that static destructors are registered.

Comment: It is compiled with /clr; I will definitely have to check this out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your ExitInstance isn't called, but it's possible to define your own DllMain by copying the contents of MFC's dllmodul.cpp file into a file in your dll and adding any extra required functionality. The procedure is documented in [this MS knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148791). Though it was written for MFC 4.0, I have used this method successfully for apps using MFC 8.0.